# Expanding ListView automatically depending to list view data adapter

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-listview

This is my layout. my list view listView_ModeOfPayment is displaying data from my adapter but in viewing it having an scroll view to view the list, i want it to be automatically expand to the parent.
My listview height is configured wrap_content. but i'm not getting the right output. what's wrong with my layout?

```
    <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >
<!-- 
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:background="#000000" >-->

        <!--  Header  Starts-->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp">
                <!-- Logo Start-->
                <ImageView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
                <!-- Logo Ends -->









          <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearTypeOfPayment"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/linearMannerOfPayment"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingTop="5dp" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewTypeOfPayment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="TYPE OF PAYMENT :"
              android:textColor="#ffffff" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewTypeOfPaymentValue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              android:text="TYPE OF PAYMENT VALUE"
              android:textColor="#ffffff"
              android:textStyle="bold" />
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewModeOfPayment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="MODE OF PAYMENT :"
              android:textColor="#ffffff" />    
      </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearTypeOfPayment"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/linearMannerOfPayment"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingTop="5dp" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewTypeOfPayment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="TYPE OF PAYMENT :"
              android:textColor="#ffffff" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewTypeOfPaymentValue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              android:text="TYPE OF PAYMENT VALUE"
              android:textColor="#ffffff"
              android:textStyle="bold" />
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewModeOfPayment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="MODE OF PAYMENT :"
              android:textColor="#ffffff" />    
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearTypeOfPayment"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/linearMannerOfPayment"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingTop="5dp" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewTypeOfPayment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="TYPE OF PAYMENT :"
              android:textColor="#ffffff" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewTypeOfPaymentValue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              android:text="TYPE OF PAYMENT VALUE"
              android:textColor="#ffffff"
              android:textStyle="bold" />
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewModeOfPayment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="MODE OF PAYMENT :"
              android:textColor="#ffffff" />    
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearTypeOfPayment"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_below="@+id/linearMannerOfPayment"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingTop="5dp" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewTypeOfPayment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="TYPE OF PAYMENT :"
              android:textColor="#ffffff" />

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewTypeOfPaymentValue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
              android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
              android:text="TYPE OF PAYMENT VALUE"
              android:textColor="#ffffff"
              android:textStyle="bold" />
          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewModeOfPayment"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="MANY TEXT VIEW FROM THE TOP OF THE LISTVIEW"
              android:textColor="#ffffff" />    
      </LinearLayout>       








        </LinearLayout>
        <!--  Header Ends -->
        <!-- Footer Start -->


        <!-- Footer Ends -->

        <!-- Login Form -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_below="@id/header"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/headerz"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:weightSum="3" 
              android:background="#f7f9f6" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/item2"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                  android:height="30dip"

                  android:text="Payment Mode"
                  android:width="275dip" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/item3"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_weight="1"

                  android:height="30dip"
                  android:text="Amount"
                  android:width="275dip" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/item4"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:height="30dip"
                  android:text="Reference #"

                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:width="275dip" />
          </LinearLayout>

          <View
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="1dip"
              android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/layoutBeforeBtnNext"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

              <ListView
                  android:id="@+id/listView_ModeOfPayment"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
              </ListView>
          </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/main1"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/footer"


            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:padding="10dp" >
          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btnBackP3"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="0.19"
              android:minHeight="45dp"
              android:text="Back" />

          <Button
              android:id="@+id/btnNextP3"
              android:layout_width="80dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="0.15"
              android:minHeight="45dp"
              android:text="Next" />
      </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>



        <!-- Login Form Ends -->
 <!--  </RelativeLayout>-->
</LinearLayout>
```

> Here is the block objects from the adapter to be display per list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal"  >

     <!--   -->  

    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/relativeModeOfPaymentCheck"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#000000" >

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearForCheck"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"

          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingTop="5dp" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewModeOfPaymentCheckValue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Mode of Payment Value check"

              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="#ffffff" />        
     </LinearLayout>
          <!-- asdasda -->
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearForAmountModeOfPayment"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearCheckDate"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="2" >

              <RelativeLayout
                  android:id="@+id/relativeBlock100"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#000000" >

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textViewModAmountCheck"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="AMOUNT"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff" />
              </RelativeLayout>

              <RelativeLayout
                  android:id="@+id/relativeBlock101"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#000000" >

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textViewModeOfPayCheckValue"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff" />
              </RelativeLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
          <!-- name of check issued -->
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearForNameCheckIssued"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearForCheck"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="2" >

              <RelativeLayout
                  android:id="@+id/relativeBlock101"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#000000" >

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textViewBankNameCheckIssued"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="RIZAL COMMERCIAL BANKING CORP."
                      android:textColor="#ffffff" />
              </RelativeLayout>
          </LinearLayout>


          <!-- CHECK NUMBER -->
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearCheckNumber"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearForNameCheckIssued"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewCheckNumber"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:text="CHECK # : "
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewCheckNumValue"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" />
          </LinearLayout>
         <!-- CHECK DATE -->
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearCheckDate"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearCheckNumber"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewCheckDate"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:text="CHECK DATE : "
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewCheckDateValue"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" />
          </LinearLayout> 


        <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearLineForCheck"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="2dp"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearForAmountModeOfPayment"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

                  <View
                      android:id="@+id/View201"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:background="#ffffff" />
          </LinearLayout>  


          </RelativeLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView cannot be used inside scrollview as in that case android will not be able to understand what to scroll(list item or complete layout) in that case.

This is a classic problem that people get into in the android development.

Solution to this is using ListView header and footer in this case. Find below steps you need to do : -

1. Remove ScrollView
2. Make everything above ListView as a seperate layout and add the same as header of your List View
3. Make everything below ListView as a seperate layout and add the same as footer of your List View

Problem Solved!!

Hope this helps..

Comment: i changed my ScrollView to linear layout. but when im displaying the objects it cuts the viewing of my layout. i could not scroll my layout. and still i don't know if my list view is filling items correctly from my adapter.

Comment: Did you add the items not part of listView as header and footer to listView?

Comment: yes i did that my footer is the button for next and back. uhm correct me if im wrong. here is my sequence of layout linear-->linearHeader-->Listview-->and my linear layout footer back and next. is this what you're trying to say..?

Comment: is it okay to give me an simple example with that, with TextViews at the top and to the middle is the expandalble ListView and to the bottom  another objects.. ? please help me i'm stuck :(

Comment: I did not get you.. You need to paste more code to help us understand where exactly are you stuck at..

Comment: please check my layout. i really dont know what's wrong with my layout

Comment: there should be 4 xmls 1. header.xml 2.footer.xml 3.This should contain only ListView and nothing else 4.Your list item XML. Then you should do something like listView.setHeader(inflated header xml) and listView.setFooter(inflated footer xml)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! actually i don't know that there was a technique like that for list view. Thanks for ur help :D

Comment: virmanji could you help me regarding my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21447659/list-view-how-to-manipulate-objects-of-list-adapter-item-view