# List view how to manipulate objects of list adapter item View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

```
adapterListView = new SpecialAdapter(getBaseContext(),list,R.layout.listview_layout,from,to);       

 headerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.jpos_ror_header, null, false);

footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.jpos_ror_footer, null, false); 



TextView tin=(TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTinValue);       
TextView textViewNameOfPayor=(TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNameOfPayor);        
TextView textViewLocation=(TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLocation);
```

> Here is my code in getting object id's from my header and footer. how can i get the view of my list view data adapter without onClick event. i want to do some layout manipulation in viewing of my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal"  >

     <!-- here is my data adapter to be display per item in list view  -->  

    <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/relativeModeOfPaymentCheck"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="#000000" >

      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearForCheck"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"

          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingTop="5dp" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textViewModeOfPaymentCheckValue"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Mode of Payment Value check"

              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="#ffffff" />        
     </LinearLayout>
          <!-- asdasda -->
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearForAmountModeOfPayment"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearCheckDate"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:weightSum="2" >

              <RelativeLayout
                  android:id="@+id/relativeBlock100"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#000000" >

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textViewModAmountCheck"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="AMOUNT"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff" />
              </RelativeLayout>

              <RelativeLayout
                  android:id="@+id/relativeBlock101"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#000000" >

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textViewModeOfPayCheckValue"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                      android:textColor="#ffffff" />
              </RelativeLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
          <!-- name of check issued -->
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearForNameCheckIssued"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearForCheck"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:visibility="gone"
              android:weightSum="2" >

              <RelativeLayout
                  android:id="@+id/relativeBlock101"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1"
                  android:background="#000000" >

                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/textViewBankNameCheckIssued"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="RIZAL COMMERCIAL BANKING CORP."
                      android:textColor="#ffffff" />
              </RelativeLayout>
          </LinearLayout>


          <!-- CHECK NUMBER -->
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearCheckNumber"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearForNameCheckIssued"
              android:visibility="gone"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewCheckNumber"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:text="CHECK # : "
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewCheckNumValue"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" />
          </LinearLayout>
         <!-- CHECK DATE -->
          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearCheckDate"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              <!-- android:visibility="gone" -->
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearCheckNumber"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewCheckDate"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                  android:text="CHECK DATE : "
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" />

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/textViewCheckDateValue"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#ffffff" />
          </LinearLayout> 


        <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/linearLineForCheck"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="2dp"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_below="@+id/linearForAmountModeOfPayment"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >

                  <View
                      android:id="@+id/View201"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:background="#ffffff" />
          </LinearLayout>  


          </RelativeLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> in this adapter i want to manipulate the view of linearlayouts by having  `LinearLAyout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE or VISIBLE);`
>
> Here i think i have some lead from my problem from the answer of himanshu. here is my listview special adapter im having problem how can get the view and viewGroup implementation to my special adapter here is my SpecialAdapter..

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    public static TextView tv;
    private int[] colors = new int[] { 0xffcccccc , 0xffffffff };
    private int[] colors2 = new int[] { 0xffffffff , 0xff000000 }; 
   // Context context;
    public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, items, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      int colorPos = position % colors.length;
      view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
      //TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewModAmountCheck);
      //textView.setText("AlvinTest");
      return view;
    }
```

> Could anyoune tell me i am doing right when im implementing mg getView2.

```
    public View getView2(Context context, int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);//get your layout inflator;

//LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, null);
        }
        LinearLayout yyy = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linearCheckDate);
        yyy.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return convertView;
    }




    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex){    
        int getIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("Name");
        String empname = cursor.getString(getIndex);
        tv = (TextView) view;
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.setText(empname);
        if(empname.equals("Any String"))
        {                   
            tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(58, 58, 224));
            return true;
        }
        return false;           
    }
}
```

> Here's my code when im calling the getView2 from my listAdapter

```
LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View v = inf.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, null);

//add magic here bu i don't know how can i get the view of these View and ViewGroup
View itemConvertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, null);
ViewGroup listParent =null; //this.getParent();//(ViewGroup)SelectorView.this.getParent();// null;
adapterListView.getView2(this,0, itemConvertView, listParent);
```

Comment: LinearLAyout.setVisibility(View.GONE or VISIBLE); try like this...

Comment: i want is to manipulate the layout items before the list view display the items.

Comment: then do this in original

Comment: i want to edit it in the code but not doing it to my xml               <!-- android:visibility="gone" -->

Answer (score 0):

try this:
Hide your Layout:

```
YourLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Visible your Layout :

```
YourLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: i want to get the view of the list view item

Comment: my task here is manipulate the objects of the listview item from the adapter of my xml written above. per one list view item theres a block of layout i want to edit their views by doing that setVisibility(). but i dont know how can i call the items with that item view of the list view..

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem correctly, you want to get the first element of the `ListView` pro grammatically and change its state (Visibility).

You can get the element in ListView by calling `getChildAt(int index)` method
e.g

```
LinearLayout yourFirstView = (LinearLayout) listview.getChildAt(0);
```

Accessing child of the element that reside in first row of the listview.

```
ViewType view = (ViewType)yourFirstView.findViewById(R.id.elementId);
```

setting the visiblity

```
yourFirstView.setVisiblity(View.Gone); // or View.VISIBLE
```

Comment: per element of the ListView i want to get the blocks of layout objects there. how can i call the specific id resource of the view of my object there from the adapter..?

Comment: look at my headerView code there i instantiated the TextView there using the headerView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTinValue); something like this procedure...

Comment: i have my xml for data adapter. that's the data i want to be manipulated. per one list item it contains the whole xml data adapter. how can i call the specified view and resource indexes of those linear layout i want to be manipulated...?

Comment: `yourFirstView.findViewById(R.id.elementId);` This is how you can access child within the each row of the listview

Comment: if view is null that means `view` is not present in the specified row. Put a debug point on `yourFirstView` and check `mChildren` to figure out who are the child view of `yourFirstView`. Then you will get to know either you are missing the view in the `yourFirstView`.

Comment: yourFirsView is null it did not see the item

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that there is some view in your ListView item which you want to show only if needed. You can do this in the getView method of your adapter where you inflate the custom layout of list item. Something like below

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = get your layout inflator;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.XXXX, null);
    }
    LinearLayout yyy = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.member_name_text_view);
    yyy.setVisibility(View.Gone)
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: how can i call this class? how can i get the parameter of the View and the ViewGroup.. i really dont know how to implement this. But i also tried something like this but it doesn't have the parameter View and ViewGroup..